# Get SmartWatch 1 and 2 display size or differentiate between the two

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Please forgive me if I have completely overlooked the obvious here, but I can't seem to find out how to from the code distinguish between the smartWatch 1 and smartWatch 2. There seem to be some differences in the hardware and display size and I want to account for that. Soo... if someone knows how to either get the current watch display size, or determine if the current watch is the SmartWatch 1 or 2 I would really appreciate it!!!

Here is what I have tried, but for both watches it seems to always return 220x176

```
public static int getSupportedControlWidth(Context context) {
    return context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.smart_watch_2_control_width);
}

public static int getSupportedControlHeight(Context context) {
    return context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.smart_watch_2_control_height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just figured out a way to make this work!! I opened up my SampleExtensionService.java file and captured the hotAppPackageName from the CreateControlExtension function. Basically I updated SampleExtensionService.java to work like this:

```
public static String hostPackage = "";
@Override
public ControlExtension createControlExtension(String hostAppPackageName) {
    hostPackage = hostAppPackageName;
    return new SampleSensorControl(hostAppPackageName, this);
}
```

Now I just call hostPackage from  SampleExtenionService like this:

```
String pkg = SampleExtensionService.hostAppPackageName
```

And now this returns either com.sonymobile.smartwatch2 or com.sonyericsson.extras.smartwatch

Seems to work great for me!! Hope that helps someone else!

------------ Edit -------------

Ok so I feel like a total idiot now!!! I am creating a control extension and right in the initialization step is the hostAppPackageName

```
SampleSensorControl(final String hostAppPackageName, final Context context) {
```

:-0!!!!! I will leave up my initial answer though in case it is useful to someone else.

Comment: Ok so I feel like a total idiot now!!! I am creating a control extension and right in the initialization step is the hostAppPackageName

Answer (score 1):

Look at the SampleControlExtension project and see how it uses:

```
DeviceInfoHelper.isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected()
```

But you can call that from anywhere if you like.

This is how the SampleExtensionService decides SW1 or SW2:

```
@Override
public ControlExtension createControlExtension(String hostAppPackageName) {
    // First we check if the API level and screen size required for
    // SampleControlSmartWatch2 is supported
    boolean advancedFeaturesSupported = DeviceInfoHelper.isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected(
            this, hostAppPackageName);
    if (advancedFeaturesSupported) {
        return new SampleControlSmartWatch2(hostAppPackageName, this, new Handler());
    } else {
        // If not we return an API level 1 control based on screen size
        final int controlSWWidth = SampleControlSmartWatch.getSupportedControlWidth(this);
        final int controlSWHeight = SampleControlSmartWatch.getSupportedControlHeight(this);
        final int controlSWHPWidth = SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro
                .getSupportedControlWidth(this);
        final int controlSWHPHeight = SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro
                .getSupportedControlHeight(this);

        for (DeviceInfo device : RegistrationAdapter.getHostApplication(this,
                hostAppPackageName)
                .getDevices()) {
            for (DisplayInfo display : device.getDisplays()) {
                if (display.sizeEquals(controlSWWidth, controlSWHeight)) {
                    return new SampleControlSmartWatch(hostAppPackageName, this, new Handler());
                } else if (display.sizeEquals(controlSWHPWidth, controlSWHPHeight)) {
                    return new SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro(hostAppPackageName, this,
                            new Handler());
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No control for: " + hostAppPackageName);
    }
}
```

Personally, I find the use of resources unnecessary, so this is how I choose to do it. I have an `enum` defined, I use the similar code to the above querying `isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected` then I pass the correct enum value around.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;

public enum ScreenConfiguration {

    SMARTWATCH1(128, 128, Config.RGB_565), SMARTWATCH2(220, 176, Config.RGB_565);

    private final int mWidth;
    private final int mHeight;
    private final Config mBitmapConfig;

    private ScreenConfiguration(int width, int height, Config bitmapConfig) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mBitmapConfig = bitmapConfig;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return mHeight;
    }

    public Config getBitmapConfig() {
        return mBitmapConfig;
    }

}
```

**EDIT** You must tell the system you want to support smartwatch 2.

In your `RegistrationInformation` class:

```
@Override
public int getTargetControlApiVersion() {
    return 2;
}
```

If that's `1`, you'll only get false for `isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected`.

**EDIT Part 2 How to use the enum**

```
@Override
public ControlExtension createControlExtension(String hostAppPackageName) {
    // First we check if the API level and screen size required for
    // SampleControlSmartWatch2 is supported
    boolean advancedFeaturesSupported = DeviceInfoHelper.isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected(
            this, hostAppPackageName);
    if (advancedFeaturesSupported) {
        return new SampleControlSmartWatch(ScreenConfiguration.SMARTWATCH2, hostAppPackageName, this, new Handler());
    } else {
        // If not we return an API level 1 control based on screen size
        final int controlSWWidth = SampleControlSmartWatch.getSupportedControlWidth(this);
        final int controlSWHeight = SampleControlSmartWatch.getSupportedControlHeight(this);
        final int controlSWHPWidth = SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro
                .getSupportedControlWidth(this);
        final int controlSWHPHeight = SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro
                .getSupportedControlHeight(this);

        for (DeviceInfo device : RegistrationAdapter.getHostApplication(this,
                hostAppPackageName)
                .getDevices()) {
            for (DisplayInfo display : device.getDisplays()) {
                if (display.sizeEquals(controlSWWidth, controlSWHeight)) {
                    return new SampleControlSmartWatch(ScreenConfiguration.SMARTWATCH1, hostAppPackageName, this, new Handler());
                } else if (display.sizeEquals(controlSWHPWidth, controlSWHPHeight)) {
                    return new SampleControlSmartWirelessHeadsetPro(hostAppPackageName, this,
                            new Handler());
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No control for: " + hostAppPackageName);
    }
}
```

Mostly the same as the first example, but see how I can use the same control class `SampleControlSmartWatch` and I pass the `ScreenConfiguration` `enum` to it, so it can know the width and height.

Comment: Hi Weston! Thanks for your detailed answer! The problem I am experiencing is that for both watches I always get the exact same results For instance this line: DeviceInfoHelper.isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected()  always returns false for me! I should also mention that I have both the SmartWatch1 and 2 connected at the same time because I need to test on both watches. And everytime I try to get width x height the values are always the same on both watches :( So I still can't distinguish which watch is active.

Comment: Sorry Weston, I actually was not able to try your enum as I do not know how to call it. Can you post an example of how to use it? Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm, first problem first, make sure you have told the system that you want to support SW2 if available, see update. Then I have added update for how to use the enum.

Answer (score 0):

For getting screen size of SmartWatch 1 you need to use `R.dimen.smart_watch_control_width` for width and `R.dimen.smart_watch_control_height` for height.

Comment: How do you call these methods? i.e. what `width` and `height` do you pass in? Seems to me, if the OP had those values, they'd not be asking the question.

Comment: The problem I am experiencing is that R.dimen.smart_watch_control_width returns the same value whether you are on the smartwatch1 or 2